# Type that describes any go function

Tags: go, functional-programming

I want to write a function that partially applies a function to an argument, like this:

```
func partial(f AnyFuncType, arg interface{}) AnyFuncType {
   return func(args ...interface{}) interface{} { 
       return f(arg, args)
   }
}

type AnyFuncType func(args ...interface{}) interface{}
```

But that doesn't work even with the simplest function like that

```
func sum(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
} 

func main() {
  addToFive := partial(sum, 5)
}
```

because I get

```
./prog.go:16:23: cannot use sum (type func(int, int) int) as type AnyFuncType in argument to partial
```

compilation error. Now, I know that I could use interface{}, but is there a way to specify a more precise type for f that would work with any function?

Comment: Go does not have generics, use an `interface{}` to describe a non-specific type.

Comment: Where do use me trying to use generics?

Comment: What you're describing is a "generic", and function signatures are not contravariant nor covariant.

Comment: They are contravariant in arguments and covariant in return types. I don't see how this is relevant to this discussion.

Comment: It is relevant, because those requirements require some sort of generics. Your `AnyFuncType` is specifically defined as `func(args ...interface{}) interface{}`, and only matches that specific function signature.

Comment: you use the reflect package to emulate such thing. But it is slow, hard to read, hard to maintain. It is also not the reason you want to use go for, so unless you have a very good reason you dont do that.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to treat `interface{}` as a generic type, but `interface{}` is not a generic type and go will not match the signature of a function that takes `interface{}` as the signature of a function that takes a concrete type.

Comment: That would be because there is no variance/covariance in GO, as JimB noted. Not necessarily generic related. It would work with variant/covariant types and interface[}.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, subtyping in GO works only for interaces. Since AnyFuncType is not an interface, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `interface{}` to represent a function of any type. There is not a more precise type that works with any function.

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to implement `partial`.

```
func partial(f interface{}, arg interface{}) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    t := v.Type()

    var in []reflect.Type
    for i := 1; i < t.NumIn(); i++ {
        in = append(in, t.In(i))
    }

    var out []reflect.Type
    for i := 0; i < t.NumOut(); i++ {
        out = append(out, t.Out(i))
    }

    var va reflect.Value
    if arg != nil {
        va = reflect.ValueOf(arg)
    } else {
        // Support `nil` as partial argument.
        va = reflect.Zero(t.In(0))
    }

    return reflect.MakeFunc(reflect.FuncOf(in, out, t.IsVariadic()),
        func(args []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
            return v.Call(append([]reflect.Value{va}, args...))
        }).Interface()
}
```

Use it like this:

```
addToFive := partial(sum, 5).(func(int) int)
fmt.Println(addToFive(1))
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IdSpsOnxeg9).

I recommend using a closure to create partials instead of the `partial` function in this answer. The closure is more efficient and avoids tricky reflect code.

```
addToFive := func(x int) int { return sum(5, x) }
fmt.Println(addToFive(1))
```